# React Query - How to update query results in a React Query with enabled option set?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

I'm using React Query for async state management in my React Native app. I've a `useQuery()` hook with following query options:

### useQuery Hook in useStudentAssignments.ts:

```
const data = useQuery(
  studentAssignmentKeys.list({
    assignedToIdEq: studentId
  }),
  async ({ queryKey: [{ params }] }) => {
      // Function to persist assignment media
  },
  {
    enabled: !!assignment && !!isConnected,
    cacheTime: Infinity,
    staleTime: Infinity,
    retry: 0,
    refetchOnReconnect: 'always',
    refetchOnMount: 'always',
    onSuccess(data) {
      // Async storage of assignments
  },
  onError() {
      // show error message
  }
}
```

### App.tsx:

In the main screen I'm using the useQuery hook as:

```
const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, isError, refetch, isStale } = useStudentAssignments(
    studentAssignment?.id
  );

useEffect(() => {
  if (!!isConnected) {
        refetch();      
 }, [refetch, isConnected);
```

}

I've these questions:

1. Since, I've `enabled` option set, my understanding is that I can't use `QueryClient.invalidateQueries()`, since it will have no effect. How else can I mark the query key as stale so that it can automatically be refresh?
2. If automatic query refresh isn't possible, how can I refresh it on some condition or state change?
3. `useQuery()` method has an async function (queryFn). Does this function runs only once, or on intervals/ every fetch?

Answer (score 1):

1. the `invalidateQueries`, `refetchQueries` is ignored only when the `enabled` is `false`. So when it becomes `true`, those function could work as your expected
2. you could call `refetch` to manually update your data. In RN, it would be called when screen/components is focused.
3. As I know, it would be triggered when an instance of `useQuery` is mounted or `refetch` called. However, they would save the result into cache, then within the cache timeout, it would return the data from cache when you call that from second instance, while queryFn is still running on background. When completed, it updates the cache data.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, make sense! In my setup I've `staleTime:Infinity`. Does this has any bearing on refetch() and cache? My understanding is that if e.g. `staleTime:1000*60`, then any refetch() issued during that minute will always return the data from cache? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `staleTime` is for marking data as fresh one, when you set it to 1 minutes, and you have another instance of that query mounted or refresh called on that interval, it would return that data from cache. It also has `cacheTime` which manage when the data on cache will be cleared.

Comment: So if I am getting it right, `staleTime:Infinity` will never mark the data to be refreshed and hence will always return data from cache?

Comment: yes, it's correct